# How to print Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER into .txt file via powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins, which calls a PowerShell script.

I would like PowerShell to print the `BUILD_NUMBER` into a txt file.

How do I retrieve the `BUILD_NUMBER` from Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins uses environment variables to store its Parameters, so `BUILD_NUMBER` can be accessed within PowerShell using this syntax `$env:BUILD_NUMBER`

And to save it to a file:

```
$env:BUILD_NUMBER | Out-File C:\folder\file.txt
```

Comment: I learned that it can be important to add: $env:BUILD_NUMBER | Out-File C:\folder\file.txt -Encoding ASCII

To make sure you can use the .txt file for other automatic operations